# "Error in tcrossprod(MModel, mmat.t) : non-conformable arguments" in mediation analysis

Tags: r

I am currently conducting a mediation analysis, where I want to measure the mediating effect of minutes played (diff_MP_FY) on the difference in performance (diff_perf_FY). I have multiple treatment variables. I get the following error message:

> Error in tcrossprod(MModel, mmat.t) : non-conformable arguments

This is the code I used:

```
model.m = lm(diff_MP_FY ~ avg_pre_injury_perf + Country  + Duration + age_at_injury 
             + line_id + first_perf_diff +
               injury_again, data = players)


model.y = lm(diff_perf_FY ~ avg_pre_injury_perf + Country  + Duration + age_at_injury 
              + line_id + first_perf_diff +
               injury_again + diff_MP_FY, data = players)

treat <- c("avg_pre_injury_perf", "Country", "Duration", "age_at_injury", 
           "line_id", "first_perf_diff", "injury_again") 

mediationmodel <- mediation::mediate(model.m, model.y, treat = treat, mediator = "diff_MP_FY")
```